# How to construct nested structs with slices

Tags: go, pointers, struct, slice

I am building a simple group manager in which I share with you the relevant part only. I am having a trouble with understanding how the things work in Object-like structs without constructors (and copy constructors in particular).

**main.go**

```
var currentGroup Headers.Group

func main() {

    currentGroup.New(0)

    p := Headers.Process{ID: uint16(len(currentGroup.Processes)), Address: "Test"}
    currentGroup.AddProcess(p)
    p.PrintProcess()
    currentGroup.PrintGroup()
}
```

I have a class-like called Process

**Process.go**

```
//Process defines a Process structure
type Process struct {
    ID      uint16
    Address string
}

type processFuncs interface {
    printProcess()
}

//PrintProcess prints a process contents
func (p Process) PrintProcess() {

    fmt.Printf("[P%d; %s]\n", p.ID, p.Address)
}
```

and a group class-like

**Group.go**

```
// Group struct
type Group struct {
    ID        uint16
    Processes []Process
}

//AddProcess adds a process to the group
func (G Group) AddProcess(p Process) {

    G.Processes = append(G.Processes, p)
}

//PrintGroup prints the group processes
func (G Group) PrintGroup() {

    fmt.Printf("=========================\nGroup %d:\n", G.ID)
    for i := 0; i < len(G.Processes); i++ {
        G.Processes[i].PrintProcess()
    }
}

//New Group Constructor
func (G Group) New(ID uint16) {
    G.ID = ID
    G.Processes = make([]Process, 0)
}
```

**Screen Output:**

```
[P0; Test]
=========================
Group 0:
```

**Expected Screen Output:**

```
[P0; Test]
=========================
Group 0:
[P0; Test]
```

**Problem:**
The `Process p` is created and printed successfully, but not added to `currentGroup`.

**Question:**
What I know is that slice `append` function copies by value. Then, a `Process` object/struct is copied without the need of creating a slice of pointers. Hence the process struct is considered as an indivisible object. Is that true? Any misunderstanding? Anything wrong with the code?

Comment: A method like `func (G Group) AddProcess(p Process)` cannot modify the receiver as G is a copy of what you pass in and you modify the copy. Use a pointer receiver. Read at least https://tour.golang.org/methods/4 ff, better the whole "Methods and interface" chapter. Your problem is probably unrelated to append and slices. For the next time: Please come up with a _minimal_ example.

Comment: Change `(G Group) AddProcess(p Process)` to `(G *Group) AddProcess(p Process)` and voilà.

Comment: I tried it and it works @mkopriva. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You are right @Volker. If I was able to detect the fault exactly, I would have solve it. I posted the minimal of what I suspect to be problematic. Anw, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I'll drop some hints for you. Which are mostly my learning when i started using golang.
Please match not only the syntax but also the casing.

```
type processFuncs interface {
    **printProcess**()
}

//PrintProcess prints a process contents
func (p Process) **PrintProcess**() {

    fmt.Printf("[P%d; %s]\n", p.ID, p.Address)
}
```

another important point: functions, methods or variables/members starting with Capital letter are exported (same as Public), starting in small case un-exported(more like private or better package level access).

You usually expose your interfaces and make the actual types unexported. Add a new method to create the type object.

Second if you want to modify the type object with the method call use pointer reference instead of value i.e.

```
Use func (p *Process) PrintProcess(){
//... do something
}
```

instead of

```
func (p Process) PrintProcess(){
//... do something
}
```

Most importantly Go is not like Java or C# or any other OO language so don't write OO code in golang.

Comment: Thanks @Ayush. Do you recommend creating the New constructor (and the make function in particular)? Although it works without it.

Comment: Since your types are already exported you don't need to write New function(constructor). But what you can do is, make the Interface exported instead and types un exported and na new method something like the following:
`
type process struct {
    id      uint16
    address string
};

type ProcessFuncs interface {
    printProcess()
};

func NewProcess() ProcessFuncs {
 return &process{}
};

`